# Cefsharp webgl failed

Tags: c#, wpf, webgl, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I cannot find a solution to the problem. Webgl doesn't work.
Here is the log

```
[0803/170929.840:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(219)] Crash reporting enabled for process: browser
[0803/170929.860:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(185)] 0E2ADC98: set chrome proxy config service to 0E2ADF40
[0803/170929.876:VERBOSE1:webrtc_internals.cc(119)] Could not get the download directory.
[0803/170929.974:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(219)] Crash reporting enabled for process: gpu-process
[0803/170930.082:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(185)] 107417D8: set chrome proxy config service to 10741980
[0803/170930.209:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(219)] Crash reporting enabled for process: utility
[0803/170930.279:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1217)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)
[0803/170930.357:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(185)] 10758AC0: set chrome proxy config service to 10758C68
[0803/170930.469:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: http://wpad/wpad.dat
[0803/170930.490:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(185)] 13333420: set chrome proxy config service to 1077D840
[0803/170930.498:VERBOSE1:simple_index_file.cc(600)] Simple Cache Index is being restored from disk.
[0803/170930.544:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: http://google.com/
[0803/170930.548:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://google.com/
[0803/170930.666:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(219)] Crash reporting enabled for process: gpu-process
[0803/170930.802:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(219)] Crash reporting enabled for process: renderer
[0803/170930.806:INFO:cpu_info.cc(53)] Available number of cores: 2
[0803/170930.845:VERBOSE1:configured_proxy_resolution_service.cc(1164)] Failed configuring with PAC script, falling-back to manual proxy servers.
[0803/170930.863:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[0803/170931.058:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1217)] The GPU process has crashed 2 time(s)
[0803/170931.179:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(219)] Crash reporting enabled for process: renderer
[0803/170931.204:INFO:cpu_info.cc(53)] Available number of cores: 2
[0803/170931.209:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(219)] Crash reporting enabled for process: gpu-process
[0803/170931.242:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[0803/170931.582:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1217)] The GPU process has crashed 3 time(s)
[0803/170931.711:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(219)] Crash reporting enabled for process: gpu-process
[0803/170931.777:VERBOSE1:gpu_init.cc(311)] gl::init::InitializeStaticGLBindingsOneOff failed
[0803/170931.876:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(152)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
```

I've tried with various settings and even without them. In this case, the CEFSHARP example works on the same machine. windows 10 x 64 CefSharp 83.4

Comment: Try setting proxy to null.  I think issue has to do with the users Browser settings.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: What CefSettings are you using? Have you got an app.manifest with the appropriate compatibility section? Really isn't a lot to go on here.